# A little help in my Mysql statement

Tags: mysql

If there's a sql select statement that get the last value of the data.

I mean like this:

database table 1

```
|id| code| name   |
|1 | abc | absent |
|2 | cbd | tabsent|
|3 | def | late   |
|4 | efg | kalant |
```

how to get the data with the end value of `ent`:

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 
WHERE (endValue of name)= "ent"
```

Comment: @491243 you should have posted as an answer instead of comment

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE name like "%ent"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE RIGHT(name, 3) = "ent"
```

would also be a possibility, instead of a `LIKE "%ent"` statement. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right

Comment: wow i think this is the best answer for what i need ^_^ ty ty ty hahahahaha